# Why does a child div's box shadow sometimes jump to the parent div?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, box-shadow

I'm trying to animate a box shadow transition with the aid of CSS pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`. In principle, the code provided in the JSFiddle works fine, except that on mousing out of the `subdiv` in the lefthand column, its box shadow jumps to the `leftparentdiv`. This behavior occurs whenever the window is window is small enough that `overflow-y: scroll` kicks in. The problem seems to occur in all browsers that support box shadows.

I guess I'm missing something obvious here, but can't figure out what.

```css
body {
    background-color: pink;
}
.subdiv {
    width: 25vw;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.subdiv:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
.subdiv:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
.subdiv:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
#leftparentdiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 47vw;
    padding: 3%;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
#rightparentdiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 53vw;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 47vw;
    padding: 3%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftparentdiv">
    <div class="subdiv">
      Blabla;
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rightparentdiv">
    <div class="subdiv">
      Blabla;
    </div>  
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kim_Fierens/0qv0dp9y/11/)

Comment: The righthand box is not doing it because it has the `overflow-y: scroll` property.

Comment: Yes, I already edited my post to reflect that. (Sorry, my bad.) In my project, the box-shadow appears on the divs where the scroll window cuts off vertically.

Comment: By the way, why do you need these styles on the pseudo-element? Why not put them on the element itself, a la https://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/vtcmywn2/1/ That way you don't even need to create a pseudo-element in your CSS.(edited to /1/ to get the exact same behavior you had with the transition)

Comment: To make the transitions smoother. See here: [link](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/) According to Ahlin, opacity is one of the few CSS properties that can be animated without constantly repainting the entire page.

Comment: Ah, I tend to do separate mobile sites with minimal flashy animations from the get-go. Not sure how much of a concern it is these days either way.

Comment: I did notice a significant difference in smoothness on my mid-2011 Macbook Air. Not the newest hardware, of course, but neither so obsolete that I can ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a transform on `.subdiv:hover`, but none on `.subdiv`. [A box with a transform establishes a containing block.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) This is what allows the pseudo-element (and its shadow) to be painted around `.subdiv` when the mouse is over it. But when the mouse leaves the element, the pseudo-element (and its shadow) jumps to `.subdiv`'s parent because `.subdiv` no longer establishes a containing block, so the pseudo-element sizes according to the parent element and not its originating `.subdiv` because the parent element does establish a containing block. This is also true when the layout is first rendered, *before* the cursor ever touches the `.subdiv` (you just don't see it because the pseudo-element is invisible).

This behavior actually occurs only when `.subdiv`'s parent has `overflow: visible`. It *doesn't* occur otherwise. The reason for that is because the pseudo-element's box shadow is actually overflowing the parent element whenever its originating `.subdiv` is not `:hover`. So a non-visible `overflow` clips the shadow away. This isn't immediately apparent because the parent element doesn't scroll — and the reason for *that* is because [box shadows don't affect layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#shadow-layers).

Assuming the desired behavior is for `.subdiv` to always be the one casting the shadow, all you have to do is position `.subdiv` so it establishes a containing block at all times:

```css
body {
    background-color: pink;
}
.subdiv {
    width: 25vw;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.subdiv:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
.subdiv:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
.subdiv:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
#leftparentdiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 47vw;
    padding: 3%;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
#rightparentdiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 53vw;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 47vw;
    padding: 3%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftparentdiv">
    <div class="subdiv">
      Blabla;
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rightparentdiv">
    <div class="subdiv">
      Blabla;
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very illuminating answer. Your solution works perfectly, and I also appreciate that you went to the trouble of explaining why the problem occurred in the first place.